# Stationary/Moving Pool Ball Detection

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project where I have to detect and track pool balls while players are playing. I tried various Background Subtraction Techniques and was able to track the moving balls but was unable to detect the stationary balls at the same time as it got adapted with the Background Model update. I can't stop the Background model update as it is necessary for changing lighting conditions. Any suggestions to achieve these goals?
SamplePoolImage

[image]

The work done so far:

1. Used opencv built-in BS algorithms like MOG2, KNN, GSOC
2. Written some algorithms like GMM, and Kalman Filter.
3. I was able to detect the moving balls/objects but the stationary balls/ objects get adapated as background after getting detected for some time.

Comment: Are you trying to replicate this: https://youtu.be/vsTTXYxydOE

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello Marek, I have seen this video earlier but not much details are provided related to ball detection and tracking. I am able to detect the moving balls but when the ball is not in motion, it gets adapted as the background which I don't want.